# Does FusionCharts support log scale for the x axis?

Tags: fusioncharts

It seems that FusionCharts only support logarithmic scales for the Y axis.
For instance, the `base:` field below is only applied to the y axis.

```
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Galaxies",
        "xAxisName": "Distance",
        "yAxisName": "Velocity",
        "base": "10",
        "theme": "fusion"
    },
```

Instead, I would like both x and y axes to use a log scale.
Is this supported in FusionChart?

Comment: on the x-axis log scale is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the document please refer if it would help you - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/logarithmic-charts

```
 {
    "chart": {
        "base": "5"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported as reported by @Zapdos13